# redirect index.php url to root domain - not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

Dear stackoverflow community users,

Here i am little bit trouble with url redirection problem.

Right now my webpage urls with index.php (http://www.mystore.com/index.php), and i am trying to redirect it on root domain with htacess file.

I place right code into htacess file but dont seems to work also if i make that blank. It also seems to not work, Website is also going to open with http://www.mystore.com/index.php url.

How can i make it proper?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: "Help, my code is not working correctly. You'll have to guess what might be wrong though, because I am not going to share my code, what error I am actually getting or what url I try to go to and what page I want to load when I go there."

Answer (score 0):

Could you try code below?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot kapa89 for the code. Its working now, but if open catagory or product page or other page it come with index page. id there any right solution for it.